# what's the difference between specifying JBOD in "storage_groups" or not

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

When ordering a SoftLayer hardware server with **DISK_CONTROLLER_RAID**  (using the `placeOrder`api call), what is the difference between listing your drives as **JBOD** (each JBOD can only list a single drive) in **storageGroups**, and not specifying them at all in **storageGroups**?  Is there a difference in how they are configured with the RAID controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the difference is the same as if you would not specify JBOD in the softlayer's control portal if you do not specify JBOD your disks will not join in a single disk you only will have separate disk.

Regards